# How can i store and access images in Mat of opencv

Tags: visual-c++, opencv

I am trying to use:

```
cv::Mat source;
const int histSize[] = {intialframes, initialWidth, initialHeight};
source.create(3, histSize, CV_8U);
```

for saving multiple images in one matrix. However when i do so, it gives me `dims = 3` and `-1` in `rows` and `cols`. 
Is it correct? 
If not what is the bug in it?
if yes how can I access my images one by one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading the documentation of the class `cv::Mat` ->[doc](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html?highlight=mat#Mat)
You can see that `cv::Mat.rows` and `cv::Mat.cols` are the number of rows and cols in a 2D array -1 otherwise.

With `source.create(3, histSize, CV_8U);` you are creating a 3D array.

In the `cv::Mat` doc is written how to access the elements. 
With the create method the matrix is continuos and in a plane-by-plane organized fashion.

---

EDIT

The first part of text in the documentation after the code of the class definition tells you how to access each element of the matrix using the `step[]` parameter of the matrix:

If you want to access the pixel `(u, v)` of the image `i` you need to get a pointer to the data and use pointer's arithmetic to reach the desired pixel:

```
int sizes[] = { 10, 200, 100 };
cv::Mat M(3, sizes, CV_8UC1);

//get a pointer to the pixel
uchar *px = M.data + M.step[0] * i + M.step[1] * u + M.step[2] * v;

//get the pixel intensity
uchar intensity = *px;
```

Comment: i have read the doc but still confused, why it is not created, if it is created how can i access it easily.. i am new to opencv so pardon me for simple silly questions. can you tell how can i access it....